# On Windows, mkbundle fails with linker error

Tags: c#, mono, mkbundle

I am trying to build a console utility that needs to be run in environments that may not have .NET installed. Mono's mkbundle seems to be a great solution for this problem, but when running mkbundle (Mono 4.6.1.3) on Windows 10 via cygwin on a trivial project, this is the output I receive:

```
$ mkbundle --deps mkbundleTest.exe -o test.exe
OS is: Windows
Sources: 1 Auto-dependencies: True
   embedding: C:\Users\Jason\Documents\mkbundleTest\mkbundleTest\bin\Debug\mkbundleTest.exe
 config from: C:\Users\Jason\Documents\mkbundleTest\mkbundleTest\bin\Debug\mkbundleTest.exe.config
   embedding: C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\4.5\mscorlib.dll
AS = as (default)
as -o temp.o temp.s
Compiling:
CC = cl.exe (default)
WINSDK = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1 (default)
VSINCLUDE = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC (default)
MONOPREFIX = C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono (default)
WARNING: Dynamically linking the Mono runtime on Windows is not a tested option.
cl.exe /MT /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\include\mono-2.0" /I "." "temp.c" "temp.o" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\monosgen-2.0.lib" /link /NODEFAULTLIB /SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup kernel32.lib version.lib Ws2_32.lib Mswsock.lib Psapi.lib shell32.lib OleAut32.lib ole32.lib winmm.lib user32.lib libvcruntime.lib advapi32.lib OLDNAMES.lib libucrt.lib /out:test.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'temp.o', object file assumed
temp.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:temp.exe
/NODEFAULTLIB
/SUBSYSTEM:windows
/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup
kernel32.lib
version.lib
Ws2_32.lib
Mswsock.lib
Psapi.lib
shell32.lib
OleAut32.lib
ole32.lib
winmm.lib
user32.lib
libvcruntime.lib
advapi32.lib
OLDNAMES.lib
libucrt.lib
/out:test.exe
temp.obj
temp.o
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\monosgen-2.0.lib"
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
libvcruntime.lib(wcschr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___isa_available
libvcruntime.lib(memcpy.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___isa_available
libvcruntime.lib(strchr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___isa_available
libucrt.lib(strnlen.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___isa_available
libvcruntime.lib(memset.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___isa_available
libvcruntime.lib(memcpy.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___isa_enabled referenced in function _memcpy
libvcruntime.lib(memset.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___isa_enabled
libvcruntime.lib(memcpy.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___favor referenced in function _memcpy
libvcruntime.lib(memset.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___favor
libucrt.lib(signal.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(winapi_thunks.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(mbctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(locale_refcounting.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(getenv.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(new_handler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(per_thread_data.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(wsetlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4
libucrt.lib(signal.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(winapi_thunks.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(mbctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(locale_refcounting.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(getenv.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(new_handler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(per_thread_data.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(wsetlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4
libucrt.lib(invalid_parameter.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __crt_debugger_hook referenced in function ___acrt_call_reportfault
libvcruntime.lib(_exsup4_.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libvcruntime.lib(_exsup_.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(initterm.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libvcruntime.lib(_chandler4_.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(getqloc_downlevel.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(lcmapstringa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(getlocaleinfoa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(exception_filter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(initctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(getstringtypea.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(get_qualified_locale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(comparestringa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(winapi_thunks.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(free_base.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(mbctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(invalid_parameter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(environment_initialization.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(new_handler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(wsetlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libvcruntime.lib(_chandler4_.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libvcruntime.lib(_exsup4_.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libvcruntime.lib(_exsup_.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(getlocaleinfoa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(initterm.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(lcmapstringa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(signal.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(initctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(getstringtypea.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(get_qualified_locale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(getqloc_downlevel.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(winapi_thunks.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(free_base.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(mbctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(exception_filter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(new_handler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(wsetlocale.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(comparestringa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(winapi_thunks.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(invalid_parameter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(invalid_parameter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(environment_initialization.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(new_handler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
libucrt.lib(wsetlocale.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function __wsetlocale_nolock
libucrt.lib(comparestringa.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __alloca_probe_16 referenced in function "int __cdecl InternalCompareStringA(struct __crt_locale_pointers *,wchar_t const *,unsigned long,char const *,int,char const *,int,int)" (?InternalCompareStringA@@YAHPAU__crt_locale_pointers@@PB_WKPBDH2HH@Z)
libucrt.lib(getstringtypea.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __alloca_probe_16
libucrt.lib(lcmapstringa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __alloca_probe_16
libucrt.lib(getlocaleinfoa.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __alloca_probe_16
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4_GS referenced in function "public: __thiscall <lambda_6e4b09c48022b2350581041d5f6b0c4c>::operator()(void)const " (??R<lambda_6e4b09c48022b2350581041d5f6b0c4c>@@QBE@XZ)
libucrt.lib(signal.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4_GS
libucrt.lib(terminate.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_epilog4_GS
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4_GS referenced in function "public: __thiscall <lambda_6e4b09c48022b2350581041d5f6b0c4c>::operator()(void)const " (??R<lambda_6e4b09c48022b2350581041d5f6b0c4c>@@QBE@XZ)
libucrt.lib(signal.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4_GS
libucrt.lib(terminate.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __SEH_prolog4_GS
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___xp_a
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___xp_z
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___xt_a
libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___xt_z
libucrt.lib(xtoa.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __aulldvrm referenced in function "int __cdecl common_xtox<unsigned __int64,char>(unsigned __int64,char * const,unsigned int,unsigned int,bool)" (??$common_xtox@_KD@@YAH_KQADII_N@Z)
libucrt.lib(atox.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __aulldvrm
libucrt.lib(atox.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __allmul referenced in function "unsigned __int64 __cdecl __crt_strtox::parse_integer<unsigned __int64,class __crt_strtox::c_string_character_source<char> >(struct __crt_locale_pointers * const,class __crt_strtox::c_string_character_source<char>,int,bool)" (??$parse_integer@_KV?$c_string_character_source@D@__crt_strtox@@@__crt_strtox@@YA_KQAU__crt_locale_pointers@@V?$c_string_character_source@D@0@H_N@Z)
libvcruntime.lib(_chandler4_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __IsNonwritableInCurrentImage referenced in function __except_handler4
libvcruntime.lib(_chandler4_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol @_guard_check_icall@4 referenced in function __except_handler4
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __load_config_used
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 22 unresolved externals
ERROR: [Fail] 2
```

To get this far, I've installed the latest windows SDK and set both the INCLUDE and LIB environment variables, but I'm a bit stuck on how to solve these linker errors.

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: Version 4.6.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after last post from me.
I tried a lot of ways.

finally , i found how to resolve this issue.

you must use mkbundle like this:

mkbundle --deps mkbundleTest.exe -o test.exe --keeptemp

the point is the --keeptemp  param.

with this param ,mkbundle will save the temp.c file on your current directory.

then copy out this line :

cl.exe /MT /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\include\mono-2.0" /I "." "temp.c" "temp.o" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\monosgen-2.0.lib" /link /NODEFAULTLIB /SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup kernel32.lib version.lib Ws2_32.lib Mswsock.lib Psapi.lib shell32.lib OleAut32.lib ole32.lib winmm.lib user32.lib libvcruntime.lib advapi32.lib OLDNAMES.lib libucrt.lib /out:test.exe

remove two params from this line: /NODEFAULTLIB /SUBSYSTEM:windows ,

the final command line like this:

cl.exe /MT /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\include\mono-2.0" /I "." "temp.c" "temp.o" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\monosgen-2.0.lib" /link /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup kernel32.lib version.lib Ws2_32.lib Mswsock.lib Psapi.lib shell32.lib OleAut32.lib ole32.lib winmm.lib user32.lib libvcruntime.lib advapi32.lib OLDNAMES.lib libucrt.lib /out:test.exe

then you will get your bundled application.

and this way working for me.

Comment: That _does_ appear to build, which is a lot closer than I've gotten before! Unfortunately the application doesn't seem to run correctly. A trivial application that only uses Console.WriteLine() doesn't seem to execute properly:
<code>
    $ ./mkbundleTest.exe
    This is a test.

    $ ./test.exe
</code>

Comment: sorry, i forgot to remind after mkbundle build to do following actions:
1. copy monosgen-2.0.dll from  C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin to your mkbundled application directory.
2. copy all of .dll files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x86 to your mkbundled application directory.

then run your application which mkbundled .
you will get your wanted result.

Comment: Great, thanks! Now it appears to work correctly. I would very much like to get --static working so that I don't need to copy two files around, but that seems an exercise for another day and a different post.

Answer (score 1):

and i'm using windows 10 and windows10sdk,the compile command is like this:

cl.exe /MT /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\um" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\shared" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\include\mono-2.0" /I "." "temp.c" "temp.o" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\monosgen-2.0.lib" /link   /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup kernel32.lib version.lib Ws2_32.lib Mswsock.lib Psapi.lib shell32.lib OleAut32.lib ole32.lib winmm.lib user32.lib libvcruntime.lib advapi32.lib OLDNAMES.lib libucrt.lib   /out:tt2.exe

and then do following actions:

1. copy monosgen-2.0.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin to your mkbundled application directory.
2. copy all of .dll files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x86 to your mkbundled application directory. then run your application which mkbundled .

you will get your wanted result.

also:

and , do not put your bundled application to non-ANSI path , 
because of the mkbundle  do not fully support the non-ANSI path on windows. 
to resolv this issue:
you can edit the temp.c file ,

typed  SetEnvironmentVariable("UTF16"); 
in method body first line : int main(int argc,char* argv[])

then your bundled application can run in any path,
but there still some issue :
in your c# application which to be mkbundle,
you can not use  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to get the application exist directory.
and another issue ,if your application use app.config ,and define some variable in appsettings .
after you bundled your application ,it can not read the variable from .config file,
the reaseon sames to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory issue.

that appears to be the mkbundled application in the creation of appdomain have bugs when processing the non-ANSI path.

i work around for this issue ,and reading the mono source code ,but there no solution has been found so far.